# C# lambda functions parsing in ANTLR

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, antlr4

What would be the grammar for parsing C# lambda expressions with ANTLR?
I'm trying to come up with one that would successfully parse at the very least a single-line lambda expression with immediate assignment, e.g.
`Action actionSingleLine = () => Console.WriteLine("Non-returning lambda");`

So far I have something like this:

```
grammar Lambda;

input: line EOF;
line: type name equals lbrackets LAMBDASIGN body ';';
type: ACTION;
name: FUNCNAME;
equals: EQ;
lbrackets: BRACKETS;
body: TEXT;

fragment A : 'A';
fragment C : 'c';
fragment T : 't';
fragment I : 'i';
fragment O : 'o';
fragment N : 'n';
fragment LPAR: '(';
fragment RPAR: ')';

ACTION: 'Action' ;
EQ : '=' ;
BRACKETS: LPAR RPAR;
LAMBDASIGN: EQ '>';
FUNCNAME: ([a-z] | [A-Z])+ ;

TEXT: 'Console.WriteLine("Non-returning lambda")';

WS : (' '|'\t')+ -> skip;
```

And the tree I get is as follows:
[image: And the tree I get is as follows:]

Comment: please make sure that the grammar you post is actually used for the results.  The `TEXT: .*;` rule in your grammar matches all of your input, and creates a token stream with a single `TEXT` token, so it wouldn't produce this tree.

Comment: You should use the [csharp grammar here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/55a4a2a2a4cbe3bc4ed2a978075a4b1861eafcde/csharp/CSharpParser.g4#L320). Just copy the grammar and support code, then augment the grammar with an EOF-terminated rule for your start symbol such as `mystart: lambda_expression EOF;`.

Comment: @MikeCargal apologies, you are right. I just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar you posted accepts your example input:

[image]

Note that the lexer rule `BRACKETS: LPAR RPAR;` should be removed because when a space is placed between the parenthesis:

```
Action actionSingleLine = ( ) => Console.WriteLine("Non-returning lambda");
```

it will not be parsed correctly. Better to remove the lexer rule and use `LPAR RPAR` directly in your parser rule:

```
grammar Lambda;

input: line EOF;
line: type name equals LPAR RPAR LAMBDASIGN body ';';
type: ACTION;
name: FUNCNAME;
equals: EQ;
body: TEXT;

LPAR: '(';
RPAR: ')';

ACTION: 'Action' ;
EQ : '=' ;
LAMBDASIGN: EQ '>';
FUNCNAME: ([a-z] | [A-Z])+ ;

TEXT: 'Console.WriteLine("Non-returning lambda")';

WS : (' '|'\t')+ -> skip;
```