# How would I parse lambda expressions in C# with ANTLR?

Tags: c#

Using [this grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/55a4a2a2a4cbe3bc4ed2a978075a4b1861eafcde/csharp/CSharpParser.g4#L320), I need to parse a file with C# code and make changes only to lambda expressions, without changing the rest of the code. How would I accomplish this? Is there a way to do it with a simpler grammar?
e.g.

```
Action actionSingleLineNoImmediateAssignment = null;
actionSingleLineNoImmediateAssignment = () => Console.WriteLine("Non-returning lambda");
```

into

```
Action actionSingleLineNoImmediateAssignment = delegate () { Console.WriteLine("Non-returning lambda"); };
```

Comment: You already have a grammar, so what's the question? Producing new code isn't parsing, it's transformation. You'll have to write code that takes the parse tree of the first example and transforms it into the second. BTW that's what Roslyn does, why go through ANTLR?

Comment: As already mentioned: what you do after parsing is up to you. ANTLR only helps with parsing, not with code generation. I've removed the ANTLR tags.

Comment: And if you're not writing your own grammar, mind as well remove this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72161023/c-sharp-lambda-functions-parsing-in-antlr

Comment: You will need to walk the parse tree produced by the parser, and look for two successive `statement` nodes, the first one being a `statement[declarationStatement/local_variable_declaration/local_variable_type//IDENTIFIER[text()='Action']]` and the second `statement[ embedded_statement/simple_embedded_statement/expression/assignment]`. You'll have to refine these searches so that you have the same local variable declared and assigned. With that in hand, you can modify the tree with what you want by deleting the two statements, and replacing with parts of first and second statement.

Comment: @kaby76 sorry, I'm a complete newbie :D How would walk the parse tree, could you provide an example please?

Comment: Nevermind, thank you all, I figured it out!